# bot framework composer creating machine learning entity

Tags: chatbot, azure-bot-service, bot-framework-composer, azure-language-understanding

I'm building a chatbot, but I don't know how to add a complex machine learning entity, what I'm trying to do is to request fullname and extract first name, second name, middle name, etc. I know how to do it by using LUIS interface bot with bot composer I feel a little confused.

Something like this, but with bot framework composer:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Language Understanding (LU) is a core component of Composer, allowing developers and conversation designers to train language understanding directly in the context of editing a dialog.

As dialogs are edited in Composer developers can continuously add to their bots' natural language capabilities through a simple markdown-like format that makes it easy to define new intents and provide sample utterances.

Here is the [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/experimental/composer-samples/javascript_nodejs/projects/actions-sample/actionssample) for Built-in Language Generation and expression library.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/file-format/bot-builder-lu-file-format?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#machine-learned-entity